# gdalcompare.py not found in GDAL 1.10.1

Tags: gdal

I cannot find the script gdalcompare.py within the osGeo distribution of GDAL by http://www.osgeo.org/. It is the 1.10.1 though. Is there any way of downloading that script separately from any other source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without downloading the whole gdal package, you can get it from http://svn.osgeo.org/gdal/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdalcompare.py

Answer (score 1):

For example by downloading Windows packages from gisinternals.com. I checked this zip-package http://gisinternals.com/sdk/Download.aspx?file=release-1600-x64-gdal-mapserver.zip and gdalcompare.py seems to be in the directory \bin\gdal\python\scripts. And source code for all the GDAL python scripts seems to be in http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts.